# Magento 1.9 How to get Guest user id in CMS pages?

Tags: magento-1.9, session, customer-group, customer-session

How to get Guest user id in CMS pages header section?

Let me know your suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: guest do not have a user id, be more specific in your question please.

Comment: If a user enter websites (not logged) need user id or cookie based id ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Mage::getModel('core/session')->getVisitorId();
```